# Contour integration of logarithm: $g(\omega) \log[1 - \chi(q,\omega)]$

Tags: logarithms, contour-integration, complex-integration

I'm trying to calculate the integral
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\mathcal{C} g(\omega) \log[1 - \chi(q,\omega)], $$
where $g(\omega) = (e^{\beta \omega}-1)^{-1}$ has an infinite number of evenly spaced poles along the imaginary axis and $\mathcal{C}$ is a curve encircling the real axis excluding the pole at $\omega = 0$ shown in the figure below.
Furthermore
$$\chi(q,\omega) = \frac{1 - 2f(q^2)}{2 q^2 - \omega}$$
with $f(\epsilon) = (e^{\beta \epsilon}+1)^{-1}.$

The answer I'm supposed to get is
$$ - \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega \; g(\omega)[ \delta(q,\omega) - \delta(q,0) ],$$
with
$$\delta(q,\omega) - \text{Arg}[1 - \chi(q,\omega + i0+)].$$
I can see that this is connected to picking up the argument by going around a branch cut situated on the negative real axis as well as excluding the pole at $\omega = 0$ in the contour $\mathcal{C}$, but I cannot make the correct arguments to obtain this result.

[image: contourintegration]

**Physics:**
For anyone interested the question arises from the evaluation of a Matsubara sum from the article Low Temp. Phys. 59, Nos. 3/4 (1985) by Nozieres and Schmitt-Rank.

Comment: You should be a bit more careful: $\delta-\delta=0$

Comment: There was a typo in the original question. The second $\delta$-function was supposed to be $\delta(q,0)$.
As far as I understand, this extra term origins from converting the integral into an integral over the full real axis, but since the point at $\omega=0$ is not within the original integration range, we have to subtract this.